Laravel 11 API: Always got unauthenticated message
I am using Laravel 11 for API with sanctum for authorization. Login works fine but logout always get unauthenticated with Http Status 401.
How to solve this problem and return HTTP status 200 as it suppose to do?
Here are my code and Postman's API request
AuthController
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Logged out successfully',
        ],200);
    }

routes/api.php
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});

Postman
{
    "name": "Logout",
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "header": [
            {
                "key": "Authorization",
                "value": "Bearer {{access_token}}"
            },
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "key": "Accept",
                "value": "application/json",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ],
        "url": {
            "raw": "{{base_url}}/api/logout",
            "host": [
                "{{base_url}}"
            ],
            "path": [
                "api",
                "logout"
            ]
        }
    },
    "response": []
},

Thanks in advance.
I tried adding gaurds but npt working
config/auth.php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],


Is this happening because the user stays on the same page after the request?
Perhaps redirect a user to the login page or home page after logout?

use middleware 'auth:api' with your current configuration instead of 'auth:sanctum'. alos make sure to run php artisan config:clear if you think the configuration is not being taken into account

@geertjanknapen There is no page redirect. It's APIs

@N69S even i changed middleware to 'auth:api', it is still not working.
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});


How do you return the sanctum token in the login response and how are you sending it in the logout request ?

No, there is indeed no redirect, but that might be the problem. It seems to me that the following is happening, which causes your error. User logs out, user stays on logout page, since user is on logout page (but already logged out) you get the Unauthenticated message since you can't be on the logout page if you're already logged out. But this is just speculation.
